# Parse all workbooks in folder and create master worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have many excel files, each with just one worksheet, in a folder that contain data from 5 sources.  The source is located in Column L.  I would like to read through each row of all files and create 5 master worksheets.  I think the number of sources should not be limited to just 5 sources, the macro should just read all rows in all files and copy the row to a master worksheet based on the value located in cell L.  The Start_Row is 3 for reading and writing.  I think I have working code for reading through each file and each worksheet but having problem with reading and writing rows

```
Sub ParseByDevice()

Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Pws As Worksheet 'Parsed Worksheet based on Column L (i, 12)
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim rw As Range
Dim cl As Range 
Dim MyBook As Workbook
Dim newBook As Workbook
Dim FileNm As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Path = "C:\xml\vac" 'Change as needed
FileName = Dir(Path & "\livevalues*.xls", vbNormal)

'
'ALL FILES IN FOLDER LOOP
'
Do Until FileName = ""
Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)

'
'ALL EACH WORKSHEET IN WORKBOOK LOOP
'
'next worksheet in file;
'only expect one worksheet but maybe more in the future
'
For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets

    '
    ' FOR EACH ROW IN WORKSHEET LOOP
    '
        rw = 3  'first row after header
        For Each rw In ws

        MsgBox Wkb.Sheets(ws).row(rw, 12).Value 'this is temporary, just a visual check that things are going well
        cl = Wkb.Sheets(ws).row(rw, 12).Value
        Wkb.Sheets(ws).row(rw, 12).Copy Pws.Sheets(cl)

    Next rw 'next row in worksheet

Next ws 'next worksheet in file;

    Wkb.Close False
    FileName = Dir()

Loop 'Do next file in folder

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can someone help me with the worksheet loop?  I want to read many workbooks and read each row, after row 3, and the contents of cell L will be the name of the Master Worksheet that I would like to write the row.  The worksheet loop is to read rows and write rows to Master Worksheets that are identified by Pws.Sheets(c1).

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Path = "C:\xml\vac" 'Change as needed
FileName = Dir(Path & "\livevalues*.xls", vbNormal)

Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook

Do Until FileName = ""

    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)

    For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets

        rw = 3  'first row after header
        Do
            tmp = ws.Cells(rw, 12).Value
            If Len(tmp) = 0 Then Exit Do

            Set Pws = Nothing

            On Error Resume Next
            Set Pws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(tmp)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Pws Is Nothing Then
                Set Pws = MyBook.Worksheets.Add( _
                   after:=MyBook.Sheets(MyBook.Sheets.Count))
                Pws.Name = tmp
            End If

            ws.Rows(rw).Copy Pws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            rw = rw + 1
        Loop

    Next ws 'next worksheet in file;

    Wkb.Close False
    FileName = Dir()

Loop 'Do next file in folder

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```